# Initializing a reference with curly braces vs parentheses

Tags: c++11, curly-brackets

I came across an issue which surprised me. I though that

```
int i = 3;
int i {3};
int i (3);
```

were equivalent.

This lead me to do (please note the t {t_} in the constructor) for the following class (exampel from Anthony Williams book C++ Concurrency in Action, so giving creds here so I don't violate some copyright issue):

```
class thread_guard{
    std::thread& t;
public:
    explicit thread_guard(std::thread& t_) : t {t_} {}
    ~thread_guard()
    {
        if(t.joinable())
            t.join();
        std::cout << "~thread_guard running" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

This gives me a compiler error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::thread&' from an rvalue of type...
```

However, changing the

```
t {t_}
```

into

```
t (t_)
```

makes it work. This of course makes me question my assumption of equivalance between the two.

Thank you for any input.

Edit: Compiler is g++, version 4.8.1 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: What compiler (include version)?  And no, they aren't equivalent in general.

Comment: Made an edit to the post.

Comment: `std::thread&' from an rvalue of type...` of what type?

Comment: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::thread&' from an rvalue of type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'

Comment: could be https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it, with target milestone 4.9.0.

Comment: @jensa yes, it works in 4.9.0